# How do I call my Cognito secured RestAPI from the browser when using next-auth?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, next-auth

I have an `AWS RestApi` secured by `AWS Cognito`. In addition to this I have a `NextJS` app using [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) that provides user authentication against the Cognito User Pool.

I now want to call the RestApi directly from the browser, but cannot find a way to include the proper credentials. Since the only cookies present in my web-app begin with `next-auth-` I assume they are not suitable for the task.

So, how do I access the access token from the browser?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up hooking up to two callbacks on the NextAuth configuration, like this:

```js
NextAuth({
    providers: [
      CognitoProvider({
        idToken: true,
        issuer,
        clientSecret,
        clientId,
        authorization,
      }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
      session: async function ({ session, token }) {
        return {
          ...session,
          bearerToken: token.bearerToken ?? session.bearerToken,
        };
      },
      async jwt({ token, account }) {
        token.bearerToken = account?.id_token ?? token.bearerToken;
        return token;
      },
    },
  })
```

From the `pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts` file.

This makes the `bearerToken` available via the `getSession` call:

```js
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

// ...

const { bearerToken } = await getSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use application like Postman to pass the `Authorization` header. I am not sure if your query is about getting the access token or about how to use the access token.

In order to get the access token and then to call your REST API, you need to have a server. Suppose you have your server with domain name "example.com". Then, put this server name in the callback URL of your Cognito user pool's app client.

After user authentication, Cognito will send the access token to "example.com". Then, you server will have the responsibility to correctly call the REST API with the access or ID token provided by Cognito.

For testing purpose, you can manually get the access token after authenticating with Cognito. Then, you can use application like Postman to make HTTP calls to your REST API endpoint with the access token. Put the token as value to the authorization header.

Comment: Sorry, not what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks anyway!